# activedirectory2 findusers call back function problem

Tags: javascript, node.js

Here is my code:

```
import ActiveDirectory from 'activedirectory2';
..........
let config = {
    attributes: { user: ["*"] },
    url: myAD,
    baseDN: 'dc=xx,dc=yy,dc=com',
    username: 'username@yy.com',
    password: 'password'
}
let missingPostList = [];
let ad = new ActiveDirectory(config); 
let staffUtil = new StaffUtil();
let staffList = await staffUtil.getStaffList();

for (let i = 0; i < staffList.length; i++) {
    staff = staffList[i];
    let query = "title=" + staff.post;
    ad.findUsers(query, function(err, users){

        if (err) {
            console.log('ERROR: ' + JSON.stringify(err));
            return;
        }
        if ((!users) || (users.length == 0)) {
            //console.log('There are no colleague title is ' + staff.post + '.');
            missingPostList.push(staff.post);
        }else {
          ...................
        }
    });
}
console.log(missingPostList);
```

When I enable the following statement,

```
console.log('There are no colleague title is ' + staff.post + '.');
```

The program shows there are 2 posts does not exist in Active Directory.

Unfortunately, when I disable the statement, it just outputs an empty array [].

In my program, if no staff posts meet the input, the following statement should be executed.

```
missingPostList.push(staff.post);
```

That means the `missingPostList` array should be modified.
However, the program output an empty array only,why the array does not have any value?
How can I fix the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found the solution:

```
import ActiveDirectory from 'activedirectory2';
..........
let config = {
    attributes: { user: ["*"] },
    url: myAD,
    baseDN: 'dc=xx,dc=yy,dc=com',
    username: 'username@yy.com',
    password: 'password'
}
let missingPostList = [];
let ad = new ActiveDirectory.promiseWrapper(config); 
let staffUtil = new StaffUtil();
let staffList = await staffUtil.getStaffList();

for (let i = 0; i < staffList.length; i++) {
    staff = staffList[i];
    let query = "title=" + staff.post;
    try{
        let users=await ad.findUsers(query);
        if ((!users) || (users.length === 0)) {
            console.log('There are no colleague title is ' + staff.post + '.');
            missingPostList.push(staff.post);
        }else {
            ..............
        }
    }catch (error){
        console.log('ERROR: ' + JSON.stringify(err));
        break;
    }
}
console.log(missingPostList);
```

According to the activedirectory2's documentation,

```
A Promise wrapper is available for all methods by an alternate require statement.
```

The following statement is in ES6 format:

```
let ad = new ActiveDirectory.promiseWrapper(config);
```